# How can I get a Div centered without it scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I need help fixing this issue. I am trying to create a webpage that has two images within a div. I want it to be centered on the screen. I have done that but I don't want it to scroll. I just want to see the full image regardless of the desktop screen size without having to scroll and also still have equal margin around the div. I am working in VScode but below is a link to what I have done so far. I will really appreciate any solution.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;   
}

body {
    font-family: poppins;
    background-color: #131313;
}

#welcome-page {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(12, 78, 136);
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 70px; 
    display: flex;       
}

.path {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="welcome-page">
            <div class="path">
                <img src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/92/98/oK5D1Z.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="path">
                <img src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/58/1/NOdDwR.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/Mike-Olas/pen/zYNVvWr

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;   
  
}

body {
    font-family: poppins;
    background-color: #131313;
    height: 100vh;
}

#welcome-page {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(12, 78, 136);
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;   
     padding: 70px; 
    height: 100%;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.path {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;

}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/pauan8/pen/KKajVpw

Comment: What is it about using display:flex and flex-direction:column, in the body that makes this work?

Comment: I updated to border-box on the child instead of flex on body. Why flex on body worked I think is because flex-basis (initial value auto) sets children to box-sizing: content-box

Comment: Great. This is what I have been cracking my brain trying to figure out for hours. I guess I kept mixing up everything.. Thanks a lot for the help Pauline...

Answer (score 0):

- Make your `<section id="welcome-page">` occupy all screen with defined padding
- Center both `.path` using flex (row)
- Make them occupy full height (but unset their background so you don't see black bleed when the images are too short in height) but max 50% width
- Center images within each using flex
- Constrain image sizes with `max-width` and `max-height`

*Snippet below rendered better in full page mode (padding appears too big on small view)*

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;   
}

body {
    font-family: poppins;
    background-color: #131313;
}

#welcome-page {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(12, 78, 136);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*width: auto;*/
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 70px; 
    display: flex;   
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.path {
    /*background-color: black;*/
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="welcome-page">
            <div class="path">
                <img src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/92/98/oK5D1Z.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="path">
                <img src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/58/1/NOdDwR.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I think I really need to understand the right properties to use in css.  Thanks Julien.....  But can you kindly explain to me what ''box-sizing'' does in the code?

Comment: @MichaelOlasanya TBH, it took me a few tries to finally get it right. It's a difficult problem

Comment: @MichaelOlasanya `box-sizing` sets how the final size of the block is determined: `border-box` means "include everything including padding and borders". Alternative is `content-box` (default) where padding and borders get added to the set size https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing